# How to create (JSON) localStorage for a (Jquery serialize) form

Tags: jquery, json

I need to create 2 input boxes, text area with a submit button. I have to use jQuery serialize array and JSON local storage. After clicking the submit button, the fields should be empty for another use and the posted data need to be shown under the "DivPrintValue" (IMP: it needs appear neat and clean on the page after submitting) and it also needs be saved after refreshing the page. this is what I have so far:

```
<div id="submitted">
    <h3>Submitted Ideas</h3>
<div id="DivPrintValue">

 </div>
</div>

<form id="titleForm">
    <h3>Add Idea</h3><br>
    <input type="text" name="title" id="title" placeholder="Title" size="38" required />
    <br>
    <textarea name="description" id="description" placeholder="description" cols="29" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('write your message here!')"></textarea>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="category" id="category" placeholder="category" size="38" />
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="add idea">
    </div>
</form>
```

**localStorage:**

```
$(function () {

// Array
var myIdeas = [];

function printToScreen(myValues) {
    if (myIdeas.length > 0) {
        $("#DivPrintValue").html('');
        myValues.forEach(function (item, index) {
            item.forEach(function (itm, indx) {
                $("#DivPrintValue").append(itm.name + " -" + itm.value + "<br>");
            })
        })
    }
}

//page load  or refreash
if (localStorage.getItem("ideas") !== null) {
    var localValues = JSON.parse(localStorage.ideas);
    if (myIdeas.length <= 0) {
        myIdeas = localValues;
    }
    printToScreen(localValues);
}

$("#titleForm").submit(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();

var formValues = $(this).serializeArray();

myIdeas.push(formValues);

localStorage.setItem("ideas", JSON.stringify(myIdeas));

var myValues = JSON.parse(localStorage.ideas);

printToScreen(myValues);

this.reset();
})

})
```

Comment: the submitted data need to appear under "submitted idea" and stay there even after refreshing the page.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a variable to store `$(this).serializeArray()` as parameter to `JSON.stringify()`, `.append()` value to `#submitted`, set value at `localStorage`, call `.reset()` method on `form` element

```js
$("form").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // serialize `form`
  var values = $(this).serializeArray();
  values.forEach(function(item, index) {
    $("#submitted").append(item.name + " " + item.value + "<br>");
  })

  // reset `form`
  this.reset();
  // set `values` at `localStorage`
  // if (!localStorage.form)
  localStorage.setItem("form", JSON.stringify(values))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="submitted">
  <h3>Submitted Ideas</h3>
</div>

<form id="titleForm">

  <h3>Add Idea</h3>
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="title" id="title" placeholder="Title" size="38" required />
  <br>
  <textarea name="description" id="description" placeholder="description" cols="29" required oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('write your message here!')"></textarea>
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="category" id="category" placeholder="category" size="38" />
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="add idea">
</form>
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"like posted comments."_ ? `form` should be reset to initial values after calling `this.reset()`

Comment: But it needs to appear without those commas and braces and should be saved on the page after refreshing. And the form keeps submitting if though it's empty. should look like this after submitting:  Title:  Read book  next line description:  blah blah  and next line category: .....

Comment: You can loop through the result of `$(this).serializeArray()` to append `name`, `value` pairs to `#submitted` , without using `JSON.stringify()`, though use `JSON.stringify()` at setting object as string at `localStorage` . After page refresh, you can , again use `JSON.parse()` to parse string version of object from `localStorage`, loop through objects within array, and append `name`, `value` to `#submitted`. Not following _"And the form keeps submitting if though it's empty. should look like this after submitting:"_ ? The `form` cannot be reset and retain values at the same time ?

Comment: I tried to the way you have recommenced but I couldn't figure out. I clicked the submit button without entering values and it kept submitting "[{"name":"title","value":""},{"name":"description","value":""},{"name":"category","value":""}]" on and on.

Comment: _"I clicked the submit button without entering values and it kept submitting "[{"name":"title","value":""},{"name":"description","value":""},{"name":"categor‌​y","value":""}]" on and on"_ Yes, the values should be empty strings if no values are entered by user. Are you trying to use the values from a previously submitted `form` at submit event when no values have been entered by user ? Not certain what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: I just need to see the submitted values inside the "submitted ideas" box without these  "{"name":"description","value":""}," and those submitted values should appear even after refreshing the page. Hope it's clear now?

Comment: Will adjust `js` at stacksnippets to display only `name`, `value` of serialized array. Though submitted values will not "appear" automatically at page refresh. You will still need to retrieve the item from `localStorage`; whether as un-formatted text, or as a string representation of an object that would be parsed in a loop and displayed.

Comment: @D.jam You can iterate objects in `values` array using `Array.prototype.forEach()`, see updated post

Comment: Yes, I got it. Now I need to figure out local storage part.

Comment: @D.jam _"local storage didn't work"_ Can you create a plnkr http://plnkr.co to demonstrate ?